# .htaccess - Allow access JUST from 127.0.0.1 to directory and its subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, localhost

As i wrote in the title i would need help blocking the access of a directory and its subdirectories, except for the localhost. I tried creating a .htaccess file and updating it to the folder i need to block, simply with this code:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

It looks working fine for the files on that directory but if i try with a file of a subdirectory the server lets me open it. I could upload that code in every subdirectory but there are many and wouldn't be really annoying, any suggestions?

Comment: What OS is your server? [Apache](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/how-to-use-htaccess/) should work fine as you've described.

Comment: Yes, is Apache.

Comment: You checked that you don't have conflict `.htaccess` files in your subdirectories?

Comment: That was the problem, i solved it. Now the problem is that with "Allow from 127.0.0.1" doesn't work, my pages can't reach the content of those folders.

Answer (score 1):

`Allow` and `Deny` were deprecated in Apache 2.4. You might have better luck with [require](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)

```
Require local
```